Windows 10 creating new virtual USB ports upon reboot or new user
We have 1 PC I'm each department for business continuity that has either an HP or a Xerox MFD installed via USB.  At first everything works and is on usb001.  Upon reboot or even a new user logging on, the OS is creating new virtual USB ports for the printer.  I have one device up to usb0035.  It does not delete the old ports and I am unable to delete them.  Our users don't have access to update the USB port to the newest one.  I am wondering else if someone else has seen this behavior or knows of a solution on how to prevent it.  I've seen where people talk about turning off UPNP, but that isn't an option.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with the introduction of the web service device (WSD) port. even though it isn't actually installed that way but has the capability.  Any help would be very appreciated.
I apologize for not spelling everything out, but I was thinking the people who would be able to help me, would know what those acronyms were.

What are "UPN" and "WSD" and did you perhaps misspell something in the first sentence of this post? Please EDIT your post and make it more clear. One good way to do this is to only use very commonly known acronyms ("USB" is pretty clean, "UPN" isn't).

universal plug n play,= upnp, looks like i forgot an 'P', my apologies WSD = Web Service Device.

@JoelWilcox - [Edit] your question.

I asked you to edit your question to clarify those. "UPNP" is used commonly enough, but WSD isn't. The first line still doesn't make any sense and your entire question suffers for it. Editing is a good thing on this site and is strongly encouraged. A big part of getting good answers is having a good question that is clear enough. This should motivate you to get that question good enough by using the edit button.
